# Get the value using xpath using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the **NO** value that is  inside the specific fieldref

```
public GetValue()
{
    (ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[contains(@fieldref =‘LineInput][@value='No'])")));
    updateLink.Click();
    return this;
}
```

but is not working

html

```
<input type="radio" autocomplete="off" fieldref="LineInput " objectref="l458D8E8BB59D4B818C2BA3417435B730" id="f_l458D8E8BB59D4B818C2BA3417435B730B7F_4_1_1" name="string_BF" class=" x-form-radio x-form-field" value="No">
```

Comment: you're missing a single quote after the word LineInput. Also, you might want to delete that single quote and type it in again (copy paste different character)

Comment: I try this and still doesn't  work for me (ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[contains(@fieldref ='LineInput')][@value='No']"))); I'm not sure what I'm missing  I get this error  invalided selector  syntaxError SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '/ is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)

Comment: .Text; after the xpath should do it

Comment: Are you trying to return the value attribute of the INPUT element you posted? Your method is called `GetValue()` but it's not returning anything and all you do is execute a click in the method. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error in your xpath expression in the way you use `contains()`; try changing it to:

```
//input[contains(@fieldref, 'LineInput')][@value='No']
```

or, alternatively:

```
//input[normalize-space(@fieldref)='LineInput'][@value='No']
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with *value* as **No** as the desired element is a dynamic element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *ElementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input.x-form-radio.x-form-field[name='string_BF'][value='No']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@class=' x-form-radio x-form-field' and @name='string_BF'][@fieldref='LineInput ' and @value='No']"))).Click();
  ```